# Findstr batch won't open while in

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

Been playing around with the findstr within a batch to get an event entry within the Windows as it's older software that doesn't do this on its own accord.

Batch opens most recent log file and checks for the word failed writing to the event log if it finds it, this works if the log file is located on my desktop but not if it's the native directory in program data:

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "C:\ProgramData\**supplier**\**application**\Backup\Logs\*.txt" /B /O:D') DO SET NewestFile=%%I

FINDSTR "failed" "%NewestFile%" 
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 EVENTCREATE /T WARNING /ID 963 /L APPLICATION /SO **application Backup** /D "**application** Backup failed"

pause
```

Thank you in advance.

Update: sorry should have mentioned I've run as admin and also ensured the file in the PD directory isn't in use. The error I get back is:

```
FINDSTR: Cannot open *.txt
```

Comment: Try running as administrator... It may require some administrative permissions to read or write from program data

Comment: Updated original post but this has been attempted, my apologies.

Comment: Please run this command, and take a look at the last line of output, `DIR "C:\ProgramData\**supplier**\**application**\Backup\Logs\*.txt" /B /O:D`. The output of that last line will be the content of `%%I` and subsequently the content of `%NewestFile%`. Okay, now as you've clearly noticed that the result is just a directory or file name, without its drive or path. How do you expect `FINDSTR` to locate it without telling it the location? Now try it with `FINDSTR "C:\ProgramData\**supplier**\**application**\Backup\Logs\%NewestFile%"`.

Comment: Thank you Compo, I see my error I've added /S to my Dir command which is output the full file path.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being a failing with my DIR request, needed the full file path with /S arguement:

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "C:\ProgramData\**supplier**\**application**\Backup\Logs\*.txt" /B /S /O:D') DO SET NewestFile=%%I

FINDSTR "failed" "%NewestFile%" 
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 EVENTCREATE /T WARNING /ID 963 /L APPLICATION /SO **application Backup** /D "**application** Backup failed"
```